# Anylogic: Parameters not readable when an agent is called

Tags: anylogic

Using this code I am calling a random available truck to then attach the trucks ID to a customer, which I match later in the model. The problem it is being called a duplicate of didn't actually exist and is not this problem. The variables are not being seen when the agent is called unless the variables are static, which I can't do. If the variables are static they are read. If they are not static the agent returns whatever the initialized value of the variable was. This is also true of parameters, as in it only returns the initialized value.

```
agent.Truck_ID = TruckCount;
TruckCount = TruckCount++;
agent.Available = 1;
Total_Trucks_In_System = Total_Trucks_In_System++;


Trucks trucks = randomWhere(Truck, t->t.Available == 1);
if (trucks!=null){
    agent.ID = trucks.Truck_ID;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anylogic model variable not updating agent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157321/anylogic-model-variable-not-updating-agent-variable)

Comment: You were already told in a different question that the information provided was not enough to help you. You were also given advice on how to proceed which you refused to do. I hope this question is closed for that reason since it's the exact same question you already asked.

Comment: I have done exactly as you asked and traced everything out. There is a lot more information here. The batched agents appear to share the same variable when it is static. If it is not static it does not pass. Parameters are not passing when a truck is grabbed either. All the code that is being used is included. Not a duplicate.

Comment: There is no new useful information... Your variables shouldn't be static... If the variable is static, if an agent changes its value... ALL the other agents will also change the value to the same thing... I don't know where you got the idea that your variables should be static... that's why you have the feeling that your agents are sharing the variable...

I repeat.. your error IS NOT here.. it's somewhere else in your model, so it will be impossible for me or any other person in the world to discover it... 

And you never informed what was the result when you did traceln.. I can't guess

Comment: The result is that for a batch of 18 there is only one variable, so the truck_ID for all 18 ends up being 18 if it is static and it passes that value. If it is not static, the initialized value of both the variable and the parameter are what passes and it passes 0 if there is no initial value there. It is all there and there was never anything about the batching being the issue, which it is because the other entry point into the model where they come in as single entities works fine when the variable is static. Parameters still dont pass. What do you want to know?

Comment: The result of traceln is the 0 and initialized values if that was not clear. I did not make that information up.

Comment: When the variable is static it passes, but it is static. If it is not static it does not pass and instead passes the initialized value of the variable. Parameters also only pass the initialized value. So if it is static the numbers are not right and if it is not static it does not pass. The trucks are being grabbed as traceln(truck.Available) is equal to 1, but only when it is static, so the bottom piece of code only sees static variables of the truck agent. The variables are updating correctly when they are not static, verified with traceln().

Comment: believe me.. your variable SHOULD NOT be static... if the traceln is 0 it means that truckCount is 0, meaning that you are reseting truckCount back to 0 somewhere in your model.. make a search and discover where you do that.

Comment: Appreciate the response. TruckCount is a model level variable and it is getting passed correctly as I can use traceln(Agent.Truck_ID) all along the trucks path and they come out fine when it is not static. After what you said about Static you are correct. Something about being static seems to make the variable visible when a truck is called. By making available static I can verify it is grabbing trucks, but when Truck_ID is not static every truck has the initialized value for that variable. When it is static it passes what ever that current value is, which is one less than TruckCount.

Comment: upload the model I will check it out, because I think this conversation is going nowhere :P

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Here is a link to the file on google drive. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v13CBQJHvKkFP3DQtjA7zmAXIz9xLEaS

Comment: The app submitted block in the upper left corner is where the customer would be matched with the truck and the New_Truck_ID block, down one section and to the right, is where the trucks entering the system are being made available and counted.

Comment: I have seen your model and your problem is major with several implicated parts that have each one several different errors... I don't think I can help you for free here... This particular error you are talking about starts from the fact that you define an initial population of 100 trucks that do not exist in your flowchart... This is a typical mistake due to the fact that when you create a population, the default initial value is 100, but you are not using these trucks in your model...
Anyways, you need major help for this... Good luck

Comment: I appreciate the help. It appears I have some fundamental issues I need to address. I was using arena about 7 years ago and have jumped in and tried to shortcut through anylogic with what I remembered from that. I am going to make sure I understand the basic here before I move forward. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up finding out after I adjusted the population to e empty as suggested is that I also needed to add in my source in the advanced portion to select custom population from the add agents to and select my trucks population. As far as being able to see variables and parameters now throughout the model this is working. Newbie mistake I am sure. Hopefully this saves someone else some time and thank you for all the help. [Picture of This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTpYF.png)